# getComputedStyle returns as expected, but getComputedStyle.anyProperty does not

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm working on a browser script and just one site doesn't work: craigslist.org/anypost. The function getComputedStyle() properly returns the object `CSSStyleDeclaration` for the element with correct values, but when I try to get the property value, it returns an incorrect value.

For example:

```
var elementBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body");      // object HTMLCollection(1)
var elementBodyAll = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"); // object HTMLCollection(42)
var elements = []                                             // array(43)
    .concat(Array.from(elementBody))
    .concat(Array.from(elementBodyAll));

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var elementStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

    console.dir(elementStyle);
    // Result: [CSSStyleDeclaration] object
    // Expanding object shows fontFamily: "\"Bitstream Vera Serif\", \"Times New Roman\", serif"

    console.dir(elementStyle.fontFamily);
    // Result: "sans-serif"
    // Expected result: "\"Bitstream Vera Serif\", \"Times New Roman\", serif"
}
```

Someone enlighten me. It works as expected on all other sites.

**Edit**

Tried some new selectors for my `var elements`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); // Same result "sans-serif"
var elements = document.getElementById("titletextonly"); // Nonexistant
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("postingtitletext"); // Same result "sans-serif"
```

The interesting one is the nonexistant one. Could the server be adding the element after my browser script has run?

Comment: How did you create/get the `elements` collection?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` is the same thing as `document.body` btw.

Comment: I wonder if the site is somehow blocking this kind of browser behavior? That's the only reason I can think why it fails on this site only. I know the site uses very robust anti-bot protections.

Comment: What happens if you exclude `body` and instead use a **single** known element from the middle of each page?